# PostgreSQL 8.4 don't work after restore

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I restore postgres data_dir from backup(backuppc). When I start postgres, I get the following error:

```
* Starting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server
* Error: could not exec /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/ -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log -s -o -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf"
```

Comment: what error, when run `/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/ -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log -s -o -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change data directory owner to postgres:

```
chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/
```